# how to interpret domain/en as domain?lang=en

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

example of a subdomain - `lorem.example.com`
the only one sinle page inside - `index.php`
and one `$_GET` param - named `lang`

`lorem.example.com/en` - should be interpreted as - `lorem.example.com?lang=en`
`lorem.example.com/de` - should be interpreted as - `lorem.example.com?lang=de`

here is my try, without success

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(en)/?$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L]  
RewriteRule ^(de)/?$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this rule:

```bash
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(en|de)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Here:

- `DirectoryIndex` is useful (if not defined in Apache config) to serve `index.php` when request is just `http://lorem.example.com`
- `(en|de)` matches and captures `en` or `de` in `$1`, that is used as value in `lang` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following .htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Make sure to keep your .htaccess and index.php files in same directory.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$  index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```